# How to update datastore in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

This is my model for storing users:

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    email = db.TextProperty(required = True)
```

Suppose this users signup, and I put there data into datastore

```
u = Post(username = joey, password = encrypt(password), email=joey@friends.com)
u.put()
u = Post(username = chandler, password = encrypt(password), email=chandler@friends.com)
u.put()
u = Post(username = ross, password = encrypt(password), email=ross@friends.com)
u.put()
```

If the user hits forgot password or change password. How do I fetch the record with either username or email as key and update there new encrpyted password?

I tried the following:

```
u = User.all().filter('username=', 'joey').fetch(10)
      for r in u: #assuming I get only one record.
        r.password = encrypt(password)
        r.put()
```

It a new another record into the Datastore. Now I have two records of **joey**.

Also tried, using GqlQuery fetch the user record and try updating the record. It throws error that "List does not have put() method defined"

Please do not link me to documentation, it gives me headache.

TL;DR: How to update datastore in GAE using user defined data as key.

EDIT: Fix code typo.

Comment: Change `wu` to `u`. Except for the fact that you're creating 3 `Post` entities (and no `User` entities), and only saving one of them in the setup, that's exactly how you do it. Although `.get()` is better than using `.fetch(10)` and iterating through what you hope is a list of one result. Well, and the fact that your code won't work at all because you're passing unquoted strings.

Comment: Code is little wrong because I missed some steps while converting my example to more generic. Main issue for me is I need code for UPDATE.

Comment: If you fetch an entity and call its `.put()` method, you will update it, unless you somehow mess with the key.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got error "List does not have put() method defined" is because GqlQuery returns a list. You should also make sure username is unique. Try below:

```
users = db.GqlQuery("select * from User where username=:1", username).fetch(1)
    if len(users) == 0:
        err = "not user with name " + username
    else:
        user = users[0]
        # change password for user
        ...
```